# how to connect the "network-speed" library for "react"?

Tags: reactjs

gives an error "URL is not a constructor"

my code https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-dust-do1d8?file=/src/App.js

library https://www.npmjs.com/package/network-speed

```
import React from "react";

const NetworkSpeed = require('network-speed');
const testNetworkSpeed = new NetworkSpeed();

async function getNetworkDownloadSpeed() {
  const baseUrl = "http://eu.httpbin.org/stream-bytes/50000000";
  const fileSizeInBytes = 50000000;
  const speed = await testNetworkSpeed.checkDownloadSpeed(
    baseUrl,
    fileSizeInBytes
  );
  console.log(speed);
}

export default function App() {
  console.log(NetworkSpeed)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => getNetworkDownloadSpeed()}>34</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use that package with React.

It's not meant for usage in browsers, but in Node.js ([where you have the `http` and `https` builtin modules, for one](https://github.com/kenigbolo/network-speed/blob/f903064c22c49571c0628df86cc8b176a4ecea2b/app.js#L1-L3)).